# module Myapp.Router.Helpers is not loaded and could not be found

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

A compilation error in an Elixir/Phoenix application:

```
== Compilation error on file web/views/layout_view.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/views/layout_view.ex:2: module Myapp.Router.Helpers is not loaded and could not be found
    expanding macro: Myapp.Web.__using__/1
    web/views/layout_view.ex:2: Myapp.LayoutView (module)
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.use/2
    web/views/layout_view.ex:2: Myapp.LayoutView (module)
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:117: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
```

My web.ex is a standard one, nothing new in it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I've seen this happening if one of the plugs imports `MyApp.Router.Helpers`, and is used in the `MyApp.Router` itself at the same time. This creates a compiler deadlock - in order to compile the router the plug is required, but in order to compile the plug, the router (and helper module) is required.

You can fix this by using fully qualified calls to the router helpers instead of importing them, i.e.

```
alias MyApp.Router.Helpers, as: Routes
Routes.foo_path(conn, :create)
```

Answer (score 8):

This also happened to me when one of my plugs contained an error and didn't compile. By commenting out the contents of my router and compiling again, I was able to see the compilation errors in my plug. After fixing them and uncommenting the contents of my router, it was able to compile normally.

Answer (score 4):

Got same error because of error in Absinthe Schema, forgot to alias some of used modules. Found it with rmarscher advice, commented all areas where MyAppWeb.Router.Helpers used and got real errors.

Comment: The same thing just happened to me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Perhaps a better fix, I replaced `MyApp` with `MyAppWeb`.  Maybe this hasn't been fixed since phoenix split off into having the `*Web` namespace be separate?

Comment: I had a related error. I was referring to the Absinthe Schema as `MyAppWeb.Schema` and it should have been `MyApp.Schema`. had another typo in that line of code.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this error after an upgrade to Phoenix 1.6 so I'll record my solution here as well in case anyone else runs into it.

For context, I'm building my app in a Docker container where I was copying over certain files and not the entire app so I could speed up builds. It looks like in 1.6 (this didn't affect 1.5) you need to have the router available when running `mix phx.digest` otherwise you get the error posted by OP.